# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making a admin-auth-guard service which prevents or allow a user based on whether it is Admin or not. while the code compiles properly and there were no error using ng-serve command. But when i a a click on any admin accessible links, i got an error in browser console which is given below.

---

### Error Message

```
core.js:4442 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null
at MapSubscriber.project (admin-auth-guard.service.ts:21)
```

---

### admin-auth-guard.service.ts

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
    import { UserService } from './user.service';
    import { AutheService } from './authe.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
    import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

 constructor(private authe: AutheService,private userService: UserService ) { }

 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authe.user$
  .pipe(switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()))
  .pipe(map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin)) //this line has error
 }
}
```

---

### user.service.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`enter code here`
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; 
import { AppUser } from '../models/app-user';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  save(user: firebase.User) {this.db.object('/user/' + user.uid).update({        
  name : user.displayName,
  email: user.email
  });
 } 
 get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
  return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
 }
}
```

---

### app-user.ts

```
export interface AppUser {
 name: string;
 email: string;
 isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Try `.pipe(map(appUser => console.log(appUser)))` to make sure that you are getting proper user object or not.

Comment: tried but getting this error:                                                                                           
Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.        Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: My bad. Try `.pipe(appUser => console.log(appUser))`.

Comment: again error : Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.ts
types.d.ts(7, 18): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Comment: Try `.pipe(tap(console.log))`

Answer (score 0):

The error means it can't find `appUser`. So it results in `isAdmin` of `undefined`.

To handle the error, change line to

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
    import { UserService } from './user.service';
    import { AutheService } from './authe.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
    import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

 constructor(private authe: AutheService,private userService: UserService ) { }

 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authe.user$
  .pipe(switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()))
  .pipe(map(appUser => appUser && appUser.isAdmin || null))
 }
}
```

To avoid error and return the right value if appUser.isAdmin else null or `false` if you want.

**The code in the comment**

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> { 
  return this.authe.user$ .pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()), 
    startWith(''), 
    map(appUser => appUser && appUser.isAdmin || null));
}
```

Comment: The error is gone from the console but the routes on which i have applied this AdminAuthGuard service weren't opening at all despite when i changed isAdmin property to true in my firebase database.So, when i click on these routes link no error messages were shown on console and also the roues remained unresponsive.

Comment: Okay
I don't think you need valueChanges() here. 

.pipe(switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()))

If you really do, add a .startWith

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authe.user$
  .pipe(switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()), startWith(''), map(appUser => appUser && appUser.isAdmin || null))
 }

Comment: i dont want use to use valueChnages() but when i remove it, (this.userService.get(user.uid))) this line has error : Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'. So, i have no choice to use use valueChanges. Secondly, when i use startWith is also throwing error i.e Cannot find name 'startWith'., although i import it on the top.

Comment: Please is it possible for you to deploy to a stackblitz.com or something so I can run and see the error?

I don't thing you need to use valueChanges() since it only triggered when the value changes.

Comment: 'https://github.com/salhotra8/TheStore.git'. Go to this link and download auth1 bracnch code of the project and run npm install and then ng serve. After that go to login link in my app, login it with google then try to open manage products or manage orders which can open only by admin, since you are not right now you should redirect to home page but nothing is happening  and with admin access ,nothing is happening also.